# Equation of Oval

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, systems-of-equations

I am thinking that, if in a lake i throw a stone then that stone creates waves which increases in radius gradually with time. 
If I do the same activity in river then i think the circle becomes oval. Can you derive an equation for such condition?

Comment: Are you saying that because the water moves faster in the middle of the river than at its edges? If so, then an oval is not the shape made. If the water is all moving at the same speed, the shape remains a circle.

Comment: I am saying that the circle that is increasing in radius starts to flow with the river and the river is flowing at constant speed. And the edge that is increasing opposite to the flow of river also flows with river and the opposite edge flows with river faster than the other. So it would create a oval shape that's perimeter is increasing. Isn't it?

Comment: Imagine the river is resting, and the earth is moving beneath it with constant speed. If we can neglect friction, what will the shape of the waves be?

Comment: @user488423  In such case you have a two dimensional wave with equation $u_{tt}=c^2\nabla^2u$ where $\nabla^2u=u_{xx}+u_{yy}$. This is monstrous equation with simple initial constrains (practically not).